# High pressure cryonics

Tags: cryonics

In this link, it is suggested to use high-pressure cryonics to freeze living cells, tissues or small organism as opposed to various and potentially toxic anti-freeze agent. The core idea is that over a certain pressure, ice is anamorphic and will not form ice crystals. Thus, organic manner will not be destroyed by said crystals.

Detailed information about the proposal can be found at this link:

https://www.benbest.com/cryonics/pressure.html

I have considering self-financing the experiment. Could anyone chip in with some advice? Do you see any red flags, design tips, etc.?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is: 1) unclear, 2) appears to not be about biology as defined in the [help], 3) requires following an external link to understand, and 4) solicits opinions and advice instead of requesting a fact-based answer. Each of these alone is sufficient reason for closure. Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and delete or [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The linked material seems quite old. High-pressure freezing of cellular and tissue samples for electron microscopy is now routine, automated machinery is commercially available: [Leica EM ICE](https://www.leica-microsystems.com/products/sample-preparation-for-electron-microscopy/p/leica-em-ice/)

I have used this machine's precursor, EM PACT2, it was able to vitrify samples up to 200 microns in diameter. The new machine is likely to have the same size limitations. Rather than pressure, what prevents the formation of ice crystals is rapid cooling; nanometer-thin samples can be vitrified at ambient pressure. Increasing the pressure slows crystal nucleation down, so heat has time to exit larger samples. The sample size cannot be increased arbitrarily, though; high pressures need a strong vessel, and thick walls will insulate the sample, preventing rapid cooling. In the EM PACT2, the copper tubes used to contain the sample would occasionally rupture from the applied pressure. Use of exotic materials might allow higher pressures with similar thermal conductivities, but it's unlikely you'd be able to reach the millimeter scale, even.

Answer (score 0):

One premise of the full proposal is that the freezing process should avoid the formation water crystals which prevent structural damage of membranes and proteins and keep the integrity of the life organism being frozen under high-pressure cryonics.

I have not seen a discussion on the thawing process which I always thought was a problem for example when thawing cells for in vitro cell culture.

For the design I would try small with for example mammalian cells like HeLa. Maybe full organisms like worms or flies for "tissues" and "full organisms".